# How can I check an exit status of a command?

Tags: perl, exit-code

I have a code snippet:

```
my @array=("abc","def", "ghi");
print "I am testing exit code\n";
grep /lan/, @array;    
if ($?) {
  print "status is 0\n";
 }
else {
  print "Status is 1\n";
}
```

I am getting "status is 1" in output, but I want "status is 0". As per my understanding, in `@array`, "lan" is not found and hence exit status must be non-zero, and thus "status is 0" should be printed.

Why is Perl not giving the right exit code? Please give a correct idea about the exit code theory if I am wrong as per my understanding above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a misuse of the [$?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$CHILD_ERROR) special variable.  You would only check that variable when you execute an **external** command via `system`, backticks, etc.  Refer to [Error variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#Error-Variables) for further details.

In your code, [grep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep) is a Perl builtin function; it should not be confused with the `grep` [unix utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) of the same name.

Instead of trying to check for an exit status, you could check the return status:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array=("abc","def", "ghi");
print "I am testing array\n";
if (grep /lan/, @array) {
  print "lan is in array\n";
}
else {
  print "lan is not in array\n";
}
```